# creating repeating items in a sharepoint list

Tags: list

Excuse my ignorance I am new to SharePoint. I am trying to create a SharePoint list for new employee application forms.

In my list I require a list of previous jobs for each applicant together with a list of previous schools and qualifications.

My question is do I need to have multiple columns (i.e. job 1 address, job 1 position, job 2 address, job 2 position, etc.) or is there a dynamic way that SharePoint will add columns as required? Is there any other easier way (i.e. a linked table) perhaps and is there a way that I can use InfoPath to exploit this?

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, there's not a way to create new fields for a list item on-the-fly, so you would need to setup those fields beforehand in the list (e.g. `Job1Address`, `Job1Position`, `Job2Address`, `Job2Position`, etc.).

I haven't used InfoPath for creating forms, so I'm not sure of it's capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to use a form library and create a custom infopath form, where you can then add Repeating Sections for the areas you want to add.

Build it in InfoPath and then upload it once you are ready and it will prompt you to add the correct reference fields etc... rather than trying to create the SharePoint columns first

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using infopath, you could create 2 related lists. One for applicants, and the other for previous jobs. You could also add a 3rd for schools or whatever. The way the lists relate is via a [lookup column](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Create-list-relationships-by-using-unique-and-lookup-columns-80a3e0a6-8016-41fb-ad09-8bf16d490632).

As for displaying them in a user friendly way, I went to a conference last year where [Mark Rackley](http://www.markrackley.net/) did a great hands-on session showing a simple way to do this. think of the applicant as the parent list and the previous jobs as the child list.

Basically he added a list view web part that displayed the child items on the parent edit forms. He then uses some JS to send the parent item ID over to the new child item form when the user clicks Add Item. On the new child item form, he sets the ID accordingly and hides the redundant field.

Mark has a [series of videos](http://www.sharepointhillbilly.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=26) that look like the same content of his presentation.